Is there a attribute or set of attributes in Azure SDK for .NET to determine if pipeline is classic or using YAML
Is there a attribute or set of attributes in Azure SDK for .NET to determine if a pipeline in Azure DevOps is using classic architecture or using YAML?

Okay I figured out how to extract above info using Azure DevOps REST API call. Just wanted info on above, thanks for the quick response

As mentioned in my answer below, there is the .NET client libraries for Azure DevOps to get the information. you can call the .NET client libraries instead of REST API in your .NET code. @MuditBalooja

You can use the .NET client libraries for Azure DevOps.
you need to install the following NuGet packages with the latest stable versions in your project:

Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.InteractiveClient


And below is a sample of the C# code as reference.
using Microsoft.Azure.Pipelines.WebApi;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi;

. . .

public static void getPipeline(string orgName, string projName, int pipID, string pat)
{
    try {
        var orgUrl = new Uri($"https://dev.azure.com/{orgName}");
        VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(orgUrl, new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, pat));
        PipelinesHttpClient pipClient = connection.GetClient<PipelinesHttpClient>();

        var get_pipe = pipClient.GetPipelineAsync(projName, pipID).Result;
        var type = get_pipe.Configuration.Type.ToString();
        Console.Write($"The type of pipeline {pipID} is {type}.");
    }
    catch(Exception ex) { 
        Console.Write(ex.ToString());
    }
}

When the pipeline is a YAML pipeline, the returned value of type is 'yaml' (or 'Yaml'). Otherwise, it is not a YAML pipeline.
If classic build pipeline, the type value should be 'designerJson'.
The corresponding REST API is "Pipelines - Get".


